# https:/3dspace/F5Health.html log in Azure application insights

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I have created one Node.Js application and I am using Azure application insights in it. Code is very simple. I have started app insights on top of `app.js`

```
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');

appInsights.setup('instrument-key-here');
appInsights.defaultClient.commonProperties = {
    'appName': 'Name-Of-MS'
};
appInsights.start();

import express from 'express';
```

I am able to see telemetry data in azure but the problem I deploy the application on the dev server (Linux)...run my application through PM2.. then I am seeing a huge volume of failed request in the portal as well.. approx 100k, 404 requests are being logged and these are not proper HTTP calls. When I detail in the portal all I see is the request URL `https:/3dspace/F5Health.html` .. that's it.

Below are details, I am seeing in the portal

```
Event time  1/24/2021, 4:48:53 PM (Local time)  
Request name    GET /3dspace/F5Health.html  
Response code   404 
Successful request  false   
Response time   1 ms    
Request URL https:/3dspace/F5Health.html    
Request Id  3e5b5c01556b9   
Performance <250ms  
Telemetry type  request 
Operation name  GET /3dspace/F5Health.html  
Operation Id    984d066c7222428c896260ea2e5 
Parent Id   984d066c7222428c8962a0ea2e5 
Application version 0.0.1   
Device type PC  
Operating system    Linux 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64    
Client IP address   0.0.0.0 
Cloud role name Web 
Cloud role instance servername.com  
SDK version node:1.8.9  
Sample rate 1
```

I am sure from where this request is being logged but it is creating a huge volume of 404 requests with the same param.

Anyone faced a similar issue. How Can I find out from where this request is being logged?

Comment: What is that file F5Health?

Comment: it is logged as HTTP request.. failed 404... not from the  code

Comment: Just guessing but it might be an ill-configured health probe that point to a non-existent resource. Does it happen on a regular interval of a few seconds? Check the PM2 configuration. I am not familiar with it but it does seem to include load balancing and monitoring, hence my guess.

Comment: PM2 is just to run the application.. where insights code is inside the code.. then how come https:/ request is logged from code ?

Comment: Because PM2 might be hitting the app, so app insight picks it up. For example, if you would have an external load balancer pinging your app for health status AI will detect that and log it.